# How do I work out if my PCIe is capable of splitting channels on a PCIe slot

Tags: motherboard, pci-express

I'm currently looking at options to repurpose an older machine (or potentially build a new storage server) in a year or two.

One rather interesting potential piece of hardware is a [card that would let me split a x16 port into 4x M.2 bay](https://archive.is/PRnTA)s (archive.is link cause aliexpress has a tendancy to do strange things with their links. Original link [here](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000126430427.html?spm=a2g0o.best.old-user.1.591c2c25NPktP1&scm=1007.28303.193168.0&scm_id=1007.28303.193168.0&scm-url=1007.28303.193168.0&pvid=37640286-4cb3-4e4d-800a-572e7e94660d))

The product write up says

> Support: Only supports motherboards that can split PCIE channels.
> Note: Not all motherboards support it, please ask the motherboard manufacturer if it is a motherboard that can split the PCIE channel.
> advantage:

The price and design indicate this is a purely passive component, but I really don't think that checking with your hardware vendor is always an option. There's clearly no PLX chip,

So practically - how do I check/know that I can split up the channels on an x16 slot into seperate channels, and would system that supported this that have any appropriate bios settings or something else I can look up?

Comment: I think the term you are looking for is "bifurcation", its possible that the manufacturer could have renamed this. Quick Google results seem to imply this is server based hardware. Personally I think its a bad idea, a not so well know manufacturer of hardware controllers only sums disaster for me :(

Comment: Well - not that *particular* one - but it does seem passive, so there's not much room to mess up. I'm pretty sure there's probably better options, but that's literally a tenth of the cost of one with a onboard controller.

Comment: I suppose its depending on what you want to achieve. Something to consider is that the speeds given in the link refer to Megabits, not megabytes. (Using phone, please see link at end.), this would result in the plugged in SSDs not being able to run at max at any one time?. Unless you have M2s to burn https://www.fullexposure.photography/how-fast-is-pcie-4-0-nvme-vs-pcie-3-0/#:~:text=How%20fast%20is%20PCIe%20NVMe,a%20tested%2031.52%20Gb%2Fs.

Comment: I will agree the better alternative is considerably more expensive. (RAID controller)

Comment: I don't think there's a generic way to find out except for (1) trying, (2) looking up/requestion information about the motherboard, or (3) looking up/requesting information about the chip(set) implementing the PCIe controller. And of course being able to see an option for this in the BIOS is a giveaway, but possibly you need to upgrade the BIOS ...